# Using WSO2 Identity Server for two LDAP servers

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have a requirement to support both external and internal users but they have to be saved in different LDAP servers. Is the WSO2 Identity Server capable of supporting two LDAP servers simultaneously and does this have something to do with multi-tenancy?
I need to register new users (both internal and external) in the relevant LDAP server, authenticate users and extract user claims through the API.

Comment: One option may be to use a [ldap proxy](http://www.ldaptools.com/ldap-proxy.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article will helps you how to configure two LDAP servers in wso2 identity server 4.0.0

1. http://pathberiya.blogspot.com/2012/11/multiple-user-store-manager-feature.html

Answer (score 2):

Current versions of WSO2 Identity Server is not capable of connecting to multiple LDAP servers. WSO2 IS use a single LDAP server in the multi-tenancy case as well.

Comment: What is the pattern of user account and groups discrimination in the WSO2 IS?

Comment: It is still possible and easy to implement a custom user store manager  (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager)  extending existing LDAP user store manager